# How do I make a simple home distillation device?

Tags: home-experiment, equipment

Like [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:Simple_distillation_apparatus.svg):
[image: distillation aparatus]

I have two medium sized glass flasks. I understand I need a T-shaped adapter from the first flask that will connect the thermometer and the condenser. So, I also need the condenser and a L-type adapter that will connect the last flask with the condenser.

Is the condenser *really* necessary for a completely beginner set up?

Do I really need the adapters? I'm worried they will not fit. How high are the costs for these parts?

Thanks for any replies. I know some theoretical chemistry stuff, but with this glassware I've got no idea what I'm doing.

EDIT: Thanks guys, I accidentally found a very nice chemical equipment store and a nice lady there sold me all the parts. I only didn't get the thermometer because it was way too expensive (and I can make something similar myself). It cost 80 eur. Flask (1l), adapter, condenser, another adapter, mount for the flask and rubber pipes. The thermometer was extra 35.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This depends on what you need this setup to accomplish, as the amount of solutions that this setup can manipulate vary greatly.

The basic consensus is that if you would want an *optimal* apparatus you would need:

- Round Bottom Flask
- Thermometer
- A Column
- Condenser (with Water In/Water Out nozzles)
- Collection Flask

Comment: It's good to know that condenser is pretty damn expensive, so it's good to find a way around as soon as you're just "home experimenting".